# 21% memory ram usage (1,7GB) in idle Windows 10, help for optimizing

Tags: windows-10, memory

Greetings people I was wondering if you consider as normal or an excess of RAM usage by the system to be using 1.7GB of RAM in idle with 21%.

The very least I have seen is 20% but occasionally I could see a maximum of 30% which equals 2.4GB of RAM.
I'm using Win10 64bits.

I added 12 pictures in the next link so  you can see either Task manager or Resource monitor, so then would appreciate a lot if there is something additional I could do for optimizing as much as humanly possible the memory RAM usage since I can imagine everything loads faster when required for working. Just being a little enthusiast. Thanks by the way for all your info.

Task manager, Resource monitor and RAMMap:

[image: task manager]

[image: resource monitor]

[image: rammap 1]

[image: rammap 2]

Comment: Umm... Sounds totally normal, what is the problem? Want to speed it up, get an SSD or faster HDD, faster processor, better graphics card, etc. because unless you are running out of RAM freeing up a few hundred megs isn't going to change anything, this isn't the days of computers with 256MB RAM where every bit of optimization helps anymore.

Comment: You have what appears to be the same screenshot multiple times.  You do this for more then one of the screenshots.  The image quality of the images also are sort of poor.  Can’t see any of the details.  I am also confused by what you believe the problem is exactly.  You should upload three of the images individually to imgur using the upload screenshot capability here and edit the links into your question

Comment: I have fixed the links already, sorry for my mistakes. I hope you can understand it now since I took them in spanish language.

Comment: You still have not made it clear, what problem you believe you have, nothing is obviously wrong from your screenshots

Comment: Oh, I was just wondering if it's too bad getting 20% of RAM(8GB) usage in Windows start which is 1.7gb and at max. 30% (2.4GB) of usage past few hours. Was just wondering if this was too much or would be some way to free some memory up. Just was enthusiast in this matter. Would appreciate your opinion about it.

Comment: post picture of [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap)

Comment: Okay, just already updated with RAMMAP pictures, Would appreciate any info additional. Thanks!

Comment: there is nothing wrong. looks ok so.

Answer (score 2):

This is a totally normal state of operation. Windows is quite hungry for memory (in comparison to e.g. Linux). So something between 1.5 and 2 GB for a running Windows 10 system is completely usual, at least in my experience. Unless your system runs out of memory, the memory usage doesn't make much a difference, performance-wise. Furthermore, most graphical applications use plenty of memory these days, so even if you might free some additional hundred megs of RAM, this won't do much of a change.

If you still think your system is slow, look into other parameters. Most Windows systems I get to see are bloated with lots of software running in the background, most of which I'd consider ransomware. So check your installed applications in the Control Panel. Second, the Hard disk is often the bottleneck in today's computer systems. The CPU can't get to it's full potential, because reading files off the disk is slow as heck. So consider getting a SSD if you don't have one, it might boost your speed by multiples.

And if you feel like you're running out of memory too fast, then get more memory, instead of squeezing every last MB out of your idle ram usage. Even in portable computers, memory still tends to be replaceble / upgradable, and it doesn't cost too much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, very well appreciated buddy. By the way I have seen a couple of this time little trick to "improve" memory performance with virtual memory trick. Would you advice to do so? (I have 8GBs of RAM) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPXQxKlK3HA

Comment: No, that’s pointless. Virtual Memory is used when physical memory is full, but the system still needs more memory. Then physical memory is freed by dumping its contents partially to disk. This is slow as heck, and should only occur very rarely, if this occurs frequently, you need more ram. The size of the page file doesn’t matter - it is not used TD 2500 the memory is full. And even if the memory is full, the size of the virtual memory file is adjusted dynamically. It comes for a reason that physical memory is expensive, or why we don’t use HDD or even SSDs instead: they’re magnitudes slower.

Comment: “Until” instead of “TD 2500” - autocorrect at its best.

Comment: Well appreciated your knowledge again Luke, thanks :-) By the way I just noticed the guys who have made those videos about Virtual memory are usually using systems with 4GB RAM or below. Sorry for my horrendous english syntax too.

Comment: Yes, noticed that as well. 4GB memory is way too less for a Windows 10 system to run well, while more than enough for a recent Linux system :) Consider your memory to small when you're often above 80% memory usage. Then try to identify the application eating all the memory, and see, if you can compress that memory usage (by opening less documents, by switching to another application) etc. If that doesn't help, buy more memory. Until that point, more memory won't speed up your computer. Fast SSDs instead do. No problem with your english :) And you're welcome!

Comment: Hey Luke, hi again. I have some parent which have a 2007 PC with Win10, with a processor AMD 2.11 GHZ Dual Core with 4GB RAM DDR2. I was just looking task manager and it says just have 3GB, 1GB reserved for hardwware (haven't done any previous tweak to RAM by the way). Is there some way to use all 4GB instead of 3GB? Unfortunately isn't as simple as switching motherboard or adding more RAM, because the technology used is really OLD with AM2 and DDR2 RAM. This could help a little bit better in performance. Thanks as always for any of your advices.

Comment: The 1GB of reserved memory is probably reserved for the graphics card. Look in the bios if you can lower that threshold. But you won’t get more than 3,5GB out of your 4GB, if there is a device that needs dedicated memory allocation. And even 4GB is really not much to run Windows 10 on. If performance is not sufficient, and buying more memory not an option, than consider installing Linux, e.g. Ubuntu, instead of or next to Windows. It is easy to understand, runs well with as low as 2GB memory, and works the same as Windows. You can do everything you‘d do on Win, except for gaming :)